# Retrieve resource from jasperserver repository using server java api

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm trying to retrieve resource from Jasperserver repository using its java API, according to  [jasper report server ultimate guide](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-ultimate-guide/v55/repository-api), I should get an instance of the ExecutionContext interface:

```
ExecutionContext context = JasperServerUtil.getExecutionContext();
```

then, get an instance of the RepositoryService interface:

```
RepositoryService repositoryService = ...; //how??
```

Now I can get the file using the following code:

```
FileResourceData fileResourceData = repositoryService.getContentResourceData(context, "/examples/report.pdf");
```

my question is how can I get the RepositoryService instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ApplicationContext ctx = StaticApplicationContext.getApplicationContext();
String repositoryServiceName = "repositoryService";
RepositoryService repositoryService = (RepositoryService) ctx.getBean(repositoryServiceName);
ExecutionContext context = JasperServerUtil.getExecutionContext();
Resource resource = repositoryService.getResource(context, fileURI);
```

Comment: Here I wrote how to get a subreport resource for manipulation in a scriptlet with your approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37961222/1915920 Thx a lot for this!